# Creating figures in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Im trying to create datatype "Figure" in Haskell, this datatype should have multiple values:

- Square (with parameter length)
- Triangle (with parameter length)
- Circle (with parameter radius)

Every figure should have a color as well (let's say black and white), this is how my code currently looks like but this doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

```
class Figure_ a where
perimeter :: a -> Double
area      :: a -> Double

data Figure = forall a. Figure_ a => Figure a

type Radius = Double
type Side   = Double
type Color  = String

data Circle    = Circle    Radius
data Triangle  = Triangle  Side
data Square    = Square    Side


instance Figure_ Circle where
perimeter (Circle r) = 2 * pi * r
area      (Circle r) = pi * r * r

instance Figure_ Triangle where
perimeter (Triangle x y) = 2*(x + y)
area      (Triangle x y) = x * y

instance Figure_ Square where
perimeter (Square s) = 4*s
area      (Square s) = s*s

instance Figure_ Figure where
perimeter (Figure shape) = perimeter shape
```

Comment: What do you mean it does not work?

Comment: I'm getting the error that forall isn't known.

Comment: If you are using `ghc`, it will tell you which option you can use to overcome this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Im trying to create datatype "Figure" in Haskell, this datatype should have multiple values:
>
> - Square (with parameter length)
> - ...
> - Circle (with parameter radius)

I'm leaving out the triangle to avoid thinking about geometry. Anyway, the questions sounds like you might want the following:

```
data Figure = Square Double | ... | Circle Double
```

And then you can define functions like:

```
area :: Figure -> Double
area (Square side) = side * side
area ... = ...
area (Circle radius) = pi * radius * radius
```

If you only need one datatype, you don't need classes in Haskell. Haskell classes are for having more than one datatype when they all support a common interface.

There is one reason to prefer your construction with `class` and `forall` over the otherwise simpler version with just `data`: In your version, it is easier to add another kind of figure that was not planned for. If you feel you need this, you might want to read about the [existential typeclass](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/) antipattern. But if you're just trying to represent figures in Haskell at all, I would certainly start with a simple datatype.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to add paramters like length in the "data Figure"?

Comment: In `data Figure = Square Double | ...`, the `Double` is the type of a parameter that is stored for all squares. If you want to store more information, just add more types there. For example, `data Figure = Square Double Color | ...`. Is that what you mean by "add parameters like length"?

Answer (score 3):

For `forall` use:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
```

Also, your triangle is accepting two parameters, so it should be like this:

```
data Triangle  = Triangle  Side Side
```

But looking at the formula of your Triangle, I think you seem to be confusing it with Rectangle. Also, indentation of your code doesn't seem to be correct. Your code should look like this:

```
class Figure_ a where
  perimeter :: a -> Double
  area      :: a -> Double
```

The same indentation rule should also be followed when you create instance of that typeclass.

Comment: Is the code for calculating the triangle correct? Also how do I calculate the sides?

Comment: @user3501483 SO isn't a forum for Maths. For calculating area and perimeter, you need to get more parameters as input.

Comment: @user3501483 To calculate the perimeter of a triangle, you need to know all of its three sides, or other parameters that can be used to determine a triangle.